# How to drop empty tables

Tags: mysql, myisam

Is it possible to drop all empty tables from my huge database (mysql)?

I'm looking for a sql command to automatically remove all those empty tables.

Currently, I have 305 tables in my dataset, and about 30% of them are old empty tables, that will not be used in my new application.

Just to clarify; All tables are of type=MyISAM

Comment: Are all tables MyISAM, InnoDB, or a mixture of both ???

Comment: They are all MyISAM

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The idea would probably be to look for the empty tables using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_ROWS =  '0'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_only'
```

Then you might be able to produce an SQL query with

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name), ';') AS query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_ROWS = '0'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_only';
```

Quick and a bit dirty, but should actually work.

Comment: ... and then you have a broken database server because you have "probably" deleted some of the mysql system tables... besides the fact that your CONCAT produces a table list without schema reference.

Comment: You also have the "right" to smartly add database restrictions to your tables, I thought it was obvious.

Comment: the answer should not take anything for granted because the answer are potentially dangerous for the user... that's all

Comment: +1 for setting up a single DROP TABLE command.

Comment: @CP: Ok I get it, my awful mistake, that's why I edited the answer. By the way, I'm a bit surprised an SQL query could actually drop a MySQL system internal table. From my perspective, that is totally broken.

Comment: @TomDesp we're here to help us ;) ... I agree with you about the possibility to drop system tables!

Comment: That's why MySQL should come with a warning label : USE AT YOUR OWN RISK !!!

Comment: This does works; your query returns a huge string containing all my empty tables. I can then cut&paste this string, and run the delete command.

I found one strange behavior from MySQL; not all my tables was removed! So I had to re-run the 'select concat(...'-query, and delete again. After the third iteration, all my empty tables was finally gone! :-)

Comment: @qualbeen I had a similar problem. The problem was that `GROUP_CONCAT` has a limit of 1024 chars (see)[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len]. Just increase it before the query `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` perhaps include that in the answer?

Comment: Problems start when tables get content between SELECT and DROP :(

Answer (score 9):

Since all tables are MyISAM, this makes my answer easier to express.

First, you need to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for the tables that have zero rows:

```
SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_rows = 0 AND table_schema NOT IN
('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema');
```

Next, formulate the query to drop the empty tables:

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') DropTableCommand
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_rows = 0 AND table_schema NOT IN
('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema');
```

Now, dump the commands into an external SQL text file.

```
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') DropTableCommand"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_rows = 0 AND table_schema"
SQL="${SQL} NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
mysql -uroot -p -ANe"${SQL}" > DropTables.sql
```

Look at the contents with one of the following

- `less DropTables.sql`
- `cat DropTables.sql`

If you are satisfied with its contents, run the script:

```
mysql -uroot -p < DropTables.sql
```

or login to mysql and run it like this:

```
mysql> source DropTables.sql
```

## Give it a Try !!!

**CAVEAT** : This technique only works with MyISAM table because the row count of a MyISAM table is physically stored in the `.MYD` of the tables. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES metadata table is always reading this and updating. DO NOT TRY THIS WITH INNODB !!!

## UPDATE 2014-02-05 11:46 EST

There is a reason I excluded `('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')`

The `mysql` schema has empty tables in it. Some `MyISAM`, some `InnoDB`, some `CSV`.

For example, here are my tables in the mysql schema for MySQL 5.6.15 on my desktop

```
mysql> select table_name,engine,table_rows
    -> from information_schema.tables
    -> where table_schema='mysql';
+---------------------------+--------+------------+
| table_name                | engine | table_rows |
+---------------------------+--------+------------+
| columns_priv              | MyISAM |          0 |
| db                        | MyISAM |          2 |
| event                     | MyISAM |          0 |
| func                      | MyISAM |          0 |
| general_log               | CSV    |          2 |
| help_category             | MyISAM |         40 |
| help_keyword              | MyISAM |        485 |
| help_relation             | MyISAM |       1090 |
| help_topic                | MyISAM |        534 |
| innodb_index_stats        | InnoDB |          0 |
| innodb_table_stats        | InnoDB |          0 |
| ndb_binlog_index          | MyISAM |          0 |
| plugin                    | MyISAM |          0 |
| proc                      | MyISAM |          0 |
| procs_priv                | MyISAM |          0 |
| proxies_priv              | MyISAM |          1 |
| servers                   | MyISAM |          0 |
| slave_master_info         | InnoDB |          0 |
| slave_relay_log_info      | InnoDB |          0 |
| slave_worker_info         | InnoDB |          0 |
| slow_log                  | CSV    |          2 |
| tables_priv               | MyISAM |          0 |
| time_zone                 | MyISAM |          0 |
| time_zone_leap_second     | MyISAM |          0 |
| time_zone_name            | MyISAM |          0 |
| time_zone_transition      | MyISAM |          0 |
| time_zone_transition_type | MyISAM |          0 |
| user                      | MyISAM |          6 |
+---------------------------+--------+------------+
28 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

If some of those tables were to disappear (like `columns_priv`, `proc_priv`, `tables_priv`, etc.), the grant mechanism may not work properly or may cause mysqld not to start up. You aso do not want to whack mysql.proc since it is the physical home of Stored Procedures. Other mechanisms may not work either should you want to use them, such as CrashSafe Replication using the InnoDB tables inside the mysql schema, or if you want to insert timezone information.

## UPDATE 2014-02-05 12:36 EST

I would like to [**commend Tom Desp for his answer for a specific reason: His syntax could do the drop without using an external script**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58293/877). Using his idea, let me capture the DROP TABLE command into a user-defined variable.

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',GROUP_CONCAT(DBTB),';')
INTO @DropCommand
FROM (SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) DBTB
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_rows = 0 AND table_schema NOT IN
('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')) A;
SELECT @DropCommand;
```

If the output of the `SELECT @DropCommand;` is correct, then execute the command like this:

```
PREPARE s FROM @DropCommand;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

This eliminates two things:

- the need for an external SQL text file
- running a separate DROP TABLE command for each table

Comment: Thanks for a long and good explanation!

+1 for returning tables across databases. This way it is easy to clean up several dataset. 

On the other hand; use with care. I run your query against "..AND table_schema = 'my_database_name'" to only work with one database (as Tom Desp suggested in an other reply)